# Powershell start transcript error

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, try-catch, transcription

I am running a powershell script from a batch file:

```
try {
  Start-Transcript -path ("C:\PS\Logs\XXXX_Session_QA_" + (Get-Date).tostring("yyyyMMdd-hhmmss-tt") + ".txt")

  <Rest of the Code>
}
catch {
  stop-transcript
}
```

Every time I run the script, I see the error

> **Error:** Transcription has not been started. Use the start-transcript command to start transcription.

I have gone through some or most of the previous posts and the code should work but it isn't triggering at all. The initial log file isn't being created either. Any idea why this could be happening or any help here?

Comment: I would recommend that you don't put a single `try{}` around all of your code. Limit `try{} catch{}` to specific commands and put handling in the `catch{}` block for *just that command*. Otherwise you can't tell which part of your code is failing and triggering the `catch{}` logic.

Answer (score 3):

Does the folder structure exist for where you are trying to write the transcript to? According to the documentation, it is required (see italics below):

> ### -Path
>
> Specifies a location for the transcript file. Enter a path to a .txt
>   file. Wildcards are not permitted. If you do not specify a path,
>   Start-Transcript uses the path in the value of the $Transcript global
>   variable. If you have not created this variable, Start-Transcript
>   stores the transcripts in the $Home\My Documents directory as
>   \PowerShell_transcript..txt files.
>
> *If any of the directories in the path do not exist, the command fails.*
>
> https://technet.microsoft.com/library/05b8f72c-ae3b-45d5-95e0-86aa1ca1908a(v=wps.630).aspx

You will also need permission to write to that path of course.

So... if the Start-Transcript cmdlet is throwing an error, you are then catching it in the `catch{}` block (invisibly) which then executes the `Stop-Transcript`.

This presumably is what is actually causing the error message: the net result is that you are trying to stop transcription when it never started in the first place.

Comment: Thanks Charlie. That makes sense. I changed the directory path and it did work. I assumed the account running the script had permissions too which was wrong. I tried everything else except change it since it was writing successfully to the folder through my account.